# Blender has stopped rendering

Tags: ubuntu, video-editing, blender

I have Blender 3.0.1 running on Ubuntu 22.04. It was installed via 'apt', not 'snap'.
I use it mostly for video editing, (vfs type stuff). I use the video editor, tracking, masking and compositing. I have had multiple successful renders from most of these, but suddenly, and without anything I can tie it to, no matter what animation I set up for rendering, it only yields a picture of a cube.

I have rebooted my system, reinstalled Blender, and the result is always the same. I have even installed Blender from scratch, including a new .config file, and immediately tried to render randomly selected, unmodified Pexel type video clips without success.

Since I have changed so many things related directly to Blender, all without any change in the result, I am beginning to think it is system software, or even computer hardware that is causing the problem.

All thoughts and suggestions are welcome.